# Storing a collection of integers in a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, integer

I have a list containing RNA base letters and a dictionary to convert them to numeric values. What I am trying to do is store these numeric values into a new list. I have:

```
RNA_list = ['C', 'G', 'A', 'U']
RNA_dictionary = {'A': 1, 'U': 2, 'C': 3, 'G': 4}
for i in RNA_list:
    if i in RNA_dictionary:
        RNA_integers = RNA_dictionary[i]
    else:
        print()
```

So RNA_integers is 3, 4, 1, 2, but I need to store them in a list somehow. I wanted to do something like:

```
RNA_integer_list = []
for i in RNA_integers:
    RNA_integer_list = RNA_integer_list + i
```

But that results in an error because the for loop can't iterate over the integers. I'm new to Python so I'm not sure how to approach this. If anyone else can help me, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Are you hoping to use this to "translate" a sequence? Not clear why `RNA_integers = [3,4,1,2]` isn't the easiest solution, unless you are going to parse a sequence like `AAAUUUCCCGGG` into `111222333444`...?

Comment: A translation table might be an excellent way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

You can do

```
RNA_list = ['C', 'G', 'A', 'U']
RNA_dictionary = {'A': 1, 'U': 2, 'C': 3, 'G': 4}
RNA_integers = []
for i in RNA_list:
    if i in RNA_dictionary:
        RNA_integers.append (RNA_dictionary[i])

print RNA_integers
```

**Output**

```
[3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Or using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
RNA_integers = [RNA_dictionary[i] for i in RNA_list if i in RNA_dictionary]
```

Comment: Or just `[RNA_dictionary[k] for k in RNA_list]`?

Comment: What if `k` is not in `RNA_dictionary`?

Comment: @thefourtheye In that case just let it fail quick and aloud?

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use `map`:

`map(RNA_dictionary.get, RNA_list)`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
RNA_dictionary.values()
```

to get `[1, 3, 2, 4]`

**EDIT**: If you need to keep the values in a similar order as RNA_list, you can use list comprehension as [thefourtheye](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19672117/2084925) suggests:

```
RNA_integers = [RNA_dictionary[i] for i in RNA_list if i in RNA_dictionary]
```

Comment: Python dicts don't keep their values in a guaranteed order.

Comment: @kojiro The OP did not mention anything about order.

Comment: OP seems to want to convert his list of RNA base letters into a list with their integer equivalents – that implies maintaining the order of the original list.

Comment: @dparpyani I think that it is a fair assumption that he wants to keep the order.

Comment: @kojiro Fair enough. I have added an edit to cover that scenario. :)

Answer (score 0):

You try this,

```
RNA_list = ['C', 'G', 'A', 'U']
RNA_dictionary = {'A': 1, 'U': 2, 'C': 3, 'G': 4}
RNA_integers = []
for i in RNA_list:
    if RNA_dictionary[i]:
        RNA_integers.append (RNA_dictionary[i])

print RNA_integers
```

out put will be

```
[3,4,1,2]
```